# Entity Framework - Nested Select Query on Selected Entry

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using [***Entity Framework Core 3.1.4***](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore/3.1.4). My Model is like-

```
public class Review
{
    [Key, Required]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public int Rating { get; set; }
    public DateTime WatchDate { get; set; }

    public virtual Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

My controller is like this-

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    var data = await _context.Reviews
                        .Include(r=>r.User)
                        .Select(r => new Review {
                            Id = r.Id,
                            WatchDate = r.WatchDate,
                            User = r.User,
                            Rating = r.Rating
                        })
                        .OrderByDescending(r => r.Rating)
                        .ToListAsync();
    return View(data);
}
```

It is doing fine, but it is querying all data of the `User` table like this (red marked areas)-

[image]

But I need only `email`, so I like to select only email (yellow marked one) from there. I am doing `Select` in the upper level, but can't do the same thing in the inside element. As far as I know, there was a way in **Entity Framework** like [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32099782/2193439). But the code is not working as version changed.

Can anyone please help, how can I accomplish it?

How can I include only user email in the list, not all data? So how can I select nested entry?

Comment: you can do something like this.

.Select(p => new
                        {
                           P.User.Email
                        })
        .AsEnumerable()

Comment: if Select is used without Include, then User will be null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try next:

```
var data = await _context.Reviews
                    .OrderByDescending(r => r.Rating)
                    .Select(r => new Review {
                        Id = r.Id,
                        WatchDate = r.WatchDate,
                        User = new User { Email = r.User.Email},
                        Rating = r.Rating
                    })                       
                    .ToListAsync();
```

But I would say better design would be to create specific `DTO` which will contain only needed properties and fill it in the `Select` clause.

Also `.Include(r=>r.User)` call is not needed cause you have `Select` clause.

Answer (score 1):

You need to map your entity in a dto (data transfer object) with exactly same fields, less User, where you add as parameter only UserEmail

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    var data = await _context.Reviews
                        .Include(r=>r.User)
                        .Select(r => new Dtos.Review {
                            Id = r.Id,
                            WatchDate = r.WatchDate,
                            UserEmail = r.User.Email,
                            Rating = r.Rating
                        })
                        .OrderByDescending(r => r.Rating)
                        .ToListAsync();
    return View(data);
}
```

So, **Reviews** from **Context** have type **Review Entity**, but **new Review** from your query have type **Dto** (both have same parameters, less User)

Anyway, a best practice is to not send entities directly to clients and map it into a dto.

Entity:

```
public class Review {
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public DateTime WatchDate {get; set;}
  public int UserId {get; set;}
  public User User {get; set;}
  public decimal Rating {get; set;}
}
```

Dto:

```
public class Review {
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public DateTime WatchDate {get; set;}
  public string UserEmail {get; set;}
  public decimal Rating {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: You don't need to write `r.User != null ? r.User.Email : null,`. EF Core will do necessary things before generating the SQL.

Comment: thanks. answer updated. For me is a good solution to prevent errors for null values. I'm too pessimistic :))

Answer (score 1):

It's always better to use `ViewModel` for the view. So First, make a `ViewModel` class as follows:

```
public class ReviewViewModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public int Rating { get; set; }
    public DateTime WatchDate { get; set; }

    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserEmail { get; set; }
}
```

Then project your query to the `ViewModel` type as follows:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    var data = await _context.Reviews
                        .Select(r => new ReviewViewModel {
                            Id = r.Id,
                            WatchDate = r.WatchDate,
                            Rating = r.Rating,
                            UserId = r.User.Id,
                            UserEmail = r.User.Email,
                        })
                        .OrderByDescending(r => r.Rating)
                        .ToListAsync();
    return View(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a [best practice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/brownfield/pros-and-cons-of-data-transfer-objects), I would suggest to [create a DTO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506472/use-of-dto-in-3-tier-architecture), which only contains the necessary data and not the database objects:

```
public class UserReviewDTO
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public int Rating { get; set; }
    public DateTime WatchDate { get; set; }
    public string UserEmail { get; set; }
}
```

You can make your query like this:

```
var data = await _context.Reviews
    .Select(r => new UserReviewDTO {
        Id = r.Id,
        WatchDate = r.WatchDate,
        UserEmail = r.User.Email,
        Rating = r.Rating
    })
    .OrderByDescending(r => r.Rating)
    .ToListAsync();
```